# Streamline with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I am trying to plot the streamlines. The problem I have is my coordinates are polar. Even when I try to convert my data to cartesian, the rows are not equal. This is not even necessary for quiver. So, is there really not a workaround to have some sort of streamlines when the "x rows" are not equal.

So basically I have X and Y which define my domain, and U,V the associated velocity field. 
When calling

```
plt.streamplot(X,Y,U,V)
```

I get the error that "x rows must be equal", which I strongly think means that that each row in X must be the same, which is not the case. My domain is skewed with a certain angle so rows in X nor Y will never be equal. How do I cope with this.

The sizes of X,Y,U,V are all equal and quadratic with shape of N x N

Note: if calling the quiver function, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What is a streamline? The tag you used refers to an obscure analysis tool - which I guess is not what you meant. Also, try to give an example of your input and the desired output.

Comment: `plt.streamplot` expects data on a grid `m x n`, if your data is irregular you could try to assign `NaN` to the elements of the grid where velocity components are not defined

Comment: Could you give some example input data?

Comment: My data is quite a lot. But basically the problem I have is that X[0,:] is not constant likewise for Y.